# Problem with API-Implementation for elevenlabs with a valid API-Key

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, text-to-speech

I don't have a big background in programming so I'd like to ask for your help. I have the following code below in python. However the output tells me that the API key is invalid (by the way I already checked and it is valid). I think it might have to do something with how the code is written for the API. the concerning API is from elevenlab, a AI-powered text-to-speech generator. What is the problem with this code? why does the output show me that the API-Key is invalid even tho the API-Key is valid.

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
import openai

from elevenlabslib import *

openai.api_key = 'API-KEY'
elevenLabsAPIKey = 'Xi-API-KEY'

r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone()
user = ElevenLabsUser(elevenLabsAPIKey)

voice = user.get_voices_by_name("Jarvis")[0]

conversation = [
        {"role": "system", "content": "Your are Jarvis from Iron man and your purpose is to be an AI assistant."},
    ]


while True:
    with mic as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source) 
        print("talk")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    word = r.recognize_google(audio)

    if "draw" in word:
        i = word.find("draw")
        i += 5
        response = openai.Image.create(
            prompt=word[i:],
            n=1,
            size="1024x1024"
        )
        image_url = response['data'][0]['url']
        print(word[i:])
        print(image_url)

    else:
        conversation.append({"role": "user", "content": word})

        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5",
        messages=conversation
        )

        message = response["choices"][0]["message"]["content"]
        conversation.append({"role": "assistant", "content": message})
        # print(message)
        voice.generate_and_play_audio(message, playInBackground=False)
```

I already checked whether the API was correct and I have not reached the limit for my subscription plan. I also looked up the instruction by elevenlabs for API implementation but I lack the skills to implement it correctly.